# Scrapy get's redirected to follow 302 and it does not crawl the site

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Scrapy gets 302 redirect to another link. In the link `'https://xxxxxx.queue-it.net?c.....com'`  Scrapy does not add the '/'. It should be`'https://xxxxxx.queue-it.net/?c.....com'`.

I have tried adding '/' in middleware.py. Under downloaderMiddleware function. But, it does not work. 
Scrapy crawls when I manually add the redirect link with '/'. However, it is not very dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Set `'dont_redirect': True` in the specific request or disable redirect globally by setting `REDIRECT_ENABLED` setting to `False`.